# Regular expression for URL accepting all file Types C#

Tags: regex, url

I need a Regular Expression to accept the URL ending with all file Types:
Like "http://other-images.contenix.com/BrandAssets/55957/care_guide.pdf" or "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9a/Avenger_-_Westphalian_horse.jpg" .

I have tried this: "^.*.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|bmp|GIF|JPEG|JPG|PNG|BMP|Gif|Jpg|Jpeg|Png|Bmp)\s*$", but this only allows only image file.

Now my requirement has changed for all File Types.

****EDIT

Can i make something like there should be a "." among the characters after the URL final slash "/"

Any Help Appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: @AvinashRaj: Not a very good approach

Comment: there are so many filetypes. How would we create a regex for you to allow all the filetypes?

Comment: If you're accepting all types, why do you need a regular expression? Just accept the type, whatever it is.

Comment: can i make something like there should be a "." among the characters after the URL final slash "/"

Comment: try `^.*\/[^.]*\.\w+\s*$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match all the URL's which contain a dot after the final `/` symbol is as below.

```
^.*\/[^.]*\.\w+\s*$
```

Comment: @Mufaddal accept anyone of the answers from here which seems more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Thats a tricky question because the types of files can be many .. as many as .. may be 500+ you can check out the list [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_formats)

Better off list all the file formats that you are to allow, and then just keep on adding them with a `|` (pipe). As you have done for image extensions.

To make sure that your url will contain a dot use :

```
^.*?\.\w+$
```

demo here : http://regex101.com/r/sL8vF1/1